# delay relay on/off

Tags: relay, delay

I have a mechanism that starts when signal is sent from a sensor. For safety reasons, I would like a delay between the mechanism can fire again.

Pseudocode of it:

```
loop
     if sensor == 1
          mechanism_fire = 1
          pause(1 second)
          mechanism_fire = 0
          pause(30 seconds)
return
```

I have read [this page](https://www.macromatic.com/blog/relays/understanding-time-delay-relay-functions#:~:text=Their%20purpose%20is%20to%20control,or%20after%20some%20time%20delay) and I think it is similar to the ON DELAY/ TRUE OFF DELAY except it needs a trigger and t1=0.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you need help with?

Comment: Could you be more specific about your problem? Because from your question is not clear what do you want to help with.

Comment: @Sahasrar Don't use answers for comments, answers should answer the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for an electrical equivalent to your pseudocode?
A simple solution would be an RC-circuit that gets discharged any time the mechanism is triggered and needs to recharge before it will allow to re-trigger.

if you are looking fore an off-the-shelf solution, there are many time-delay relays available that will stay "on" for a certain time after being triggered - which would be in parallel with your mechanism. If it offers an normally closed output as well, this could be used to open the trigger line and inhibit activation of the mechanism for a certain time. If not, use a second relay to get the opener action.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHVN66.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>